# How install associate function in R

Tags: r

i get this error, how can i isntall associate function

Error in associate(x, y, method = "pearson", mode = "matrix", p.adj.threshold = 0.05,  :
could not find function "associate"

Comment: You will need to install a package to get that function,  but there is more than one package with an `associate` function.  At least `lsa` and `regclass` have such functions.   What are you trying to do?  How did you decide to use this function?

Comment: i am doing a tutorial to plot a heat map. This tutorial starts by library(microbiome) # Load libraries
library(phyloseq)
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
library(knitr)

Comment: did you install these libraries first, and did they load properly?

Comment: one of this libaries i coudln't install it because i get this error :  Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘microbiome’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages

Answer (score 1):

Your package `microbiome` is part of Bioconductor, so you install using `BiocManager`:

```
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
    install.packages("BiocManager")

BiocManager::install("microbiome")
```

Comment: Yes i did it Thank you very much  :)

Comment: You're welcome. Happy to help.  Please mark the question as answered to close.

Comment: 0

Again i have the same problem, i am installing these pachages but i have an error a the end : if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE)) install.packages("BiocManager")

BiocManager::install("phyloseq", force= TRUE) BiocManager::install("microbiome")

Warning messages: 1: In file.copy(savedcopy, lib, recursive = TRUE) : problem copying E:\zee\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\00LOCK\rlang\libs\x64\rlang.dll to E:\zee\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\rlang\libs\x64\rlang.dll: Permission denied

Comment: So this one is a different issue. You have insufficient permissions. You need to close RStudio and open R as administrator (right click on R to do that). Then install the package there. Once that's done you can open RStudio again and it should work.

Comment: I tried , i have the same problem. Not working

Comment: I suggest you close this question and open a new question for this package then, as it's a different error.